# Record Agora Group video call in single screen in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: laravel, flutter, agora.io, agora-implementation, agora-cloud-recording

I have build video calling Application in flutter and backend API in laravel.
For Video Call At Flutter side I'm Using Agora_UIkit. and With help of Agora Rest API for Cloud Recording I' recording video.
currently i have record the video call session but problem i'm facing is that, agora storing video call in 2 separate mp4 files. and I want a single Video file where User can View Video of both side.

Comment: hi, i have the same kind of issue have you figured it out?

Comment: Yes sure! please explain here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was Just passed Agora ID Received from Agora Rest API, but instead of that just have to pass unique keys for recording Session(if not passed agora will take Unique key itself).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).